# How to count the contents of one column by two others with awk?

Tags: unix, awk, count, cygwin

Say I have a file with three columns, as follows:

```
00:00:01  Login     Steve
00:00:01  Install   Sarah
00:00:01  Install   Sarah
00:00:02  Explorer  Sarah
00:00:02  Explorer  Sarah
00:00:02  Install   Steve
00:00:02  Firewall  Sarah
00:00:02  Logout    Steve
00:00:04  Logout    Sarah
```

Is it possible to use awk to count up the unique actions each user performs in each time stamp, so the output is something like this:

```
00:00:01 Steve Login 1
00:00:01 Sarah Install 2
00:00:02 Sarah Explorer 2
00:00:02 Steve Install 1
00:00:02 Sarah Firewall 1
00:00:02 Steve Logout
00:00:04 Sarah Logout
```

This is the closest I've come:

```
awk '{count[$1,$3,$2]++}END{for (i in count){split(i,a,SUBSEP); print a[1],a[2],count[i]}}' awktest.txt
```

Which give me this result:

```
00:00:02 Sarah 1
00:00:02 Steve 1
00:00:02 Steve 1
00:00:01 Steve 1
00:00:04 Sarah 1
00:00:02 Sarah 2
00:00:01 Sarah 1
00:00:01 Sarah 1
```

I'm doing this in Cygwin.

Comment: Why do the last two lines of your desired output not have counts?

Comment: what's your actual question? you state the problem, and what you've done to solve it.

Comment: So  you wrote code that prints 2 of the 3 indices of the array and 1 of the 3 indices is missing from the output. What COULD the problem be....

Comment: to answer your Q "Is it possible to use awk to count up the unique actions each user performs ...". YES, it's possible AND you're very close. note the hints you're getting in the msg above. You're almost there. Also, I've upvoted your Q, as  you provided sample input, required output, current output and some code. This makes your Q in my book a well constructed Q. Keep posting and Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk -F"\t" -v OFS="\t" '{arr[$0]+=1} END {for(i in arr) print i,arr[i]}' test.in
00:00:01        Install Sarah   2
00:00:04        Logout  Sarah   1
00:00:02        Firewall        Sarah   1
00:00:01        Login   Steve   1
00:00:02        Logout  Steve   1
00:00:02        Install Steve   1
00:00:02        Explorer        Sarah   2
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks!

Since I'm fairly new **to**

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks!

Since I'm fairly new to awk, I looked over your statement to see if I could understand how each part works.  Is this an accurate evaluation?

`-F"\t"` : sets the field separator as tab.
`-v` : pass variables to script.
`OFS="\t"` : sets output separator field to tab.
`{arr[$0]+=1}` : look at current line and add 1 to it's value ech time it occurs.
`END` : Perform final actions of script.
`{for(i in arr) print i, arr[1]}` : For the variable i in the array, print the value of i where arr is a function of i.

Comment: `arr[$0]+=1`: use current record `$0` as key to array `arr` and accumulate that array element's value by one. `for(i in arr) print i, arr[1]}`: for each array `arr` element print its key and value.