# Sed copy pattern between range only once

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am using sed to edit some sql script.  I want to copy all the lines from the first "CREATE" pattern until the first "ALTER" pattern.  The issue I am having is that sed copies all lines between each set of CREATE and ALTER instead of only the first occurrence (more than once).

```
sed -n -e '/CREATE/,/ALTER/w createTables.sql' $filename
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38467115/how-to-count-the-contents-of-one-column-by-two-others-with-awk for an example of a well documented Q. With sample data that can be copy/pasted by the reader, (along with required VS current output), it will be much easier to help. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using sed

```
 sed -n '/CREATE/,/ALTER/{p;/ALTER/q}' file > createTables.sql
```

or alternatively(note the newline)

```
sed -n '/CREATE/,/ALTER/{w createTables.sql
/ALTER/q}' file
```

Answer (score 3):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -ne 'print if /CREATE/ .. /ALTER/ && close ARGV' -- "$filename" > createTables.sql
```

It closes the input when the ALTER is matched, i.e. it doesn't read any further.

Comment: thanks.  don't know any perl yet but seems like it's time to pick up a scripting language.